# Nested div inside django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have model form with output `as.p()`, now I need to wrap one or few fields with div to get very different styling. Need to do this in view I think because form come on the page on the ajax call, I can't loop over form fields in template. How to do this?

Comment: @israelord,@Vladimir Prudnikov, I just update question because I can't loop over fields

Comment: it must be `{% for field in form %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the form fields. Take a look at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the form fields

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

or, you can just put the field you want:

```
<div class="control-panel">
    <div class="control-group">
        Name: {{ form.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

There are better ways to do this, check django's doc